# picker view one component hide and other component unhide

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

i tired two component in picker view i.e (currency),(id) and showed but my question is how to hide "id" component alone in picker view."currency" in responseArray and "id" in responseArray1.

picker view delegate:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;{
    return 2;

}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;{
        return [responseArray count];
    }

-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;{
    //return [responseArray objectAtIndex:row];
    if (component == 0) {
        return [responseArray objectAtIndex:row];
    } else {
        return [responseArray1 objectAtIndex:row];


    }
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{

    NSLog([responseArray1 objectAtIndex:row]);
    if (component == 0) {
        [pickerView selectRow:row inComponent:1 animated:YES ];
    } else if(component == 1)
    {
        if (row != [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0])
        {
            [pickerView selectRow:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] inComponent:1 animated:YES];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So, what you want exactly ? not getting your question properly

Comment: two component in picker view one component want to hide and other component want to unhide @Lion

Comment: When want to hide and when want to unhide? and if you require only one component at a time then why you return 2 ?

Comment: i need two component present but while showing in pickerview one component want to hide because second component i want in did select row viewed in nslog so i put return 2. @Lion

Comment: for that you not need to return two component. you have two array so you can show one in picker view and can direct pick value from second array. I am writing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as per comments :

```
 -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;{
return 1;

}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return [responseArray count];
}

-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{


return [responseArray objectAtIndex:row];



}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

NSLog(@"rsponse currency : %@",[responseArray objectAtIndex:row]);
NSLog([responseArray1 objectAtIndex:row]);



// You can fetch value from both array using row parameter.
// You can display currency and id for particular row from here like above

}
```

You not need to display two component in pickerview. Just display one which you want to show and according to selected row you can fetch respective element from array.

Hope this will help :)